# non-bijective morphism between indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional Algebra. Let $M$ and $N$ be indecomposable $A$-modules.
> Suppose $f: M \rightarrow N$ is not an isomorphism. Then $f$ doesn't admit a left or right inverse.

I guess I don't know enough about indecomposable modules to prove this. Can anybody help?

Comment: A left or right inverse might allow you to produce a nontrivial submodule.

Comment: Actually having a left or right inverse might also imply injectivity / surjectivity which could yield some contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a $g$ such that $f \circ g$ is the identity, then $f$ is surjective. Since $f$ is not an isomorphism, it's not an injection, and hence $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ is a nontrivial submodule of $M$. This yields a nontrivial decomposition of $M$ as $\operatorname{Ker}(f) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(g)$. To see this, notice that an element $m \in M$ can be written as $\big(m - g(f(m))\big) + g(f(m))$, and that $\operatorname{Ker}(f) \cap \operatorname{Im}(g) = \{0\}$. Such a decomposition is in contradiction with the indecomposability of $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer :) But why is it a contradiction that $\text{Ker}(f)$ is a nontrivial submodule of $M$? After all $M$ is assumed to be indecomposable and not simple.

Comment: ahh got it! Because then $f$ would be a split epimorphism, right?

Comment: Oh, right, I'm being sloppy, sorry. Hang on...

Comment: I altered my answer a bit. [Hope it's right now. :) ]